# How to explain to the 店員 that I'm an "inverted triangle" body type?

Tags: translation, meaning

Recently went to buy some shirts to wear at work, I exercise a lot (cardio, weight-training and calisthenics) so I have pretty large shoulders and a (smaller? regular?) waist.

I tried explaining that I'm an "inverted triangle" body type and was told something called "Y体", at first I thought it made sense but when I tried them on, the ones that fit my waist I couldn't even get my forearms into, and the ones that fit my shoulders and arms were like 1.5 times the size of my waist, came to the conclusion that this "Y体" is just a "rectangle" body type (why it's called "Y" beats me...).

How would I explain an "inverted triangle" body type in Japanese?

Comment: @muru 「店員」Yeah, totally got that mixed up! lol Will fix it. Thanx

Comment: Were those "Y" shirts just normal dress shirts? Because dress shirts are called ワイシャツ in Japanese (thought not 「Y型」). Note that the ワイ here comes from "white" and not the letter "Y".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal translation, 逆【ぎゃく】三角形【さんかっけい】(型【がた】)(の体型/ボディー) makes perfect sense ([`逆三角形 体型` on Y! image search](https://search.yahoo.co.jp/image/search?ei=UTF-8&fr=sfp_as&aq=-1&oq=&ts=3177&p=%E9%80%86%E4%B8%89%E8%A7%92%E5%BD%A2%E3%80%80%E4%BD%93%E5%9E%8B&meta=vc%3D)).

I have no idea what a Y型のボディー is (it may be jargon used by someone, though).

Comment: Sorry, maybe should have used「Y体型」in my question...

Comment: Thanx I'll try 逆三角形 next time.